# custome css in google/yahoo map

Tags: google-maps, yahoo-maps

how to generate cutom marker and icons like trulia in google/yahoo maps

Answer (score 1):

You can check here for some [utilities](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/) or you can implement yourself a custom marker following the [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers)